# Reflection: Show bytecode type signature of static types

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

Is it possible to show the full type signature (with erased parameterized types) saved in the bytecode with the new Reflection library?

For example the type

```
Any => Unit
```

should be displayed as

```
"scala.Function1<java.lang.Object,scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>"
```

because that's the type stored in the bytecode. It is possible to show this type with `javap`. First one needs to compile some code with `scalac`:

```
object X {
  def m(f: Any => Unit) = f
}
```

The command `javap -c -s -l -verbose X$` shows:

```
...
const #25 = Asciz   (Lscala/Function1<Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;>;)Lscala/Function1<Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;>;;
...
public scala.Function1 m(scala.Function1);
  Signature: (Lscala/Function1;)Lscala/Function1;
...
```

The output of `javap` is a bit weird I'm more interested to get "Java like" output. Maybe a string which represents the type signature a even better a type which could easily generate this string.

Another example:

```
package abc
object O {
  def x(i: Int)(j: Int) = i+j
}

// type of x should be displayed something like
"int abc.O$.x(int, int)"
```

Is something like this already supported and if not how to build such an output for any types?

Answer (score 0):

Types are already the full type signatures, but they do not include the complete path. For that, you'd have to go to the symbol and get its owner, or something like that.

Every question about the new reflection has been doing that, so if you could be more specific, it would help.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> typeOf[abc.O.type].member(newTermName("x")).typeSignatureIn(typeOf[abc.O.type])
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = (i: scala.Int)(j: scala.Int)scala.Int
```

Comment: I'm interested in a string representation of the type signature as it is saved in the bytecode. In your code sample, for example the multiple parameter lists should only displayed as one parameter list because multiple parameter lists don't exist in JVM bytecode.

Comment: @sschaef Then your question doesn't make sense. Bytecode signature is erased, so `Any => Unit` is just `Function1`.

Comment: The signature is not erased (not fully). javap shows for `Any => Unit` the signature `Lscala/Function1<Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;>`.

Comment: @sschaef WHERE? Do you create a file with just `Any => Unit` in it, compile and then javap shows that? Doubtful. You are not providing enough information, and you'll not get useful answers until you do. Stop skimping on details.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question a little bit. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: @sschaef The public signature is what bytecode knows: `Function1`, as I said. The const you are seeing is the type that *Scala* stores, which is what I have shown in the answer.

Comment: I don't think this is the ScalaSignuture because when I compile equivalent Java code the same signature is saved to the bytecode: https://gist.github.com/3190447