# Get a string representation for a closure in scala

Tags: scala

```
scala> val f = (x:Int) => x+1
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> println(f)
<function1>
```

Is it possible to print the `f: Int => Int = <function1>` string within a program (not console)? I mainly need the `Int => Int` part for testing purposes.

Comment: Just FYI, ``f`` here is a function, not a closure. A closure would be something like: ``val f = (x: Int) => x + more``

Comment: Thanks! I am new with scala and functional programming.

Comment: No worries, you can read more here: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html if you are interested :)

Comment: to be more precise it's a function1 (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) ^_^

Comment: Functions compile down to instances of generic function traits, as @bacon noted, so I doubt you'll be able to get more than the cardinality reliably...

Comment: Basically the input and output types are type parameters of the `Function1` class, hence are not available at runtime due to type erasure. You can get at them at runtime if you use Scala reflection (TypeTags etc), but that is rather specialized and advanced, and best avoided if you're a beginner. It would be better to revise your testing approach.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about type erasure. I wasn't familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe **:type** is what you want

```
scala> val f = (x:Int) => x+1
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> :type f
Int => Int
```

Since you wanna get it in program, then TypeTag maybe a choice

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.reflect.runtime.{ universe => ru }
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{ TypeTag, typeTag }
def getTypeTag[T: TypeTag](o: T) = typeTag[T].tpe

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

scala> val f = (x:Int) => x+1
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> getTypeTag(f)
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Int => Int

scala> getTypeTag(f).toString
res1: String = Int => Int
```

Comment: Thanks, this is cleaner than f.getClass. Can I use `:type` inside a program? (I edited my question to clarify this is what I want)

Comment: I am afraid not, this is for the REPL, if you wanna use that in program maybe you have to use reflection with TypeTag to get the type of f.

Comment: Yeah I came across a question where someone tried to extract that information too, but it did not seem totally relevant to the OP so I did not mention it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659570/reflection-show-bytecode-type-signature-of-static-types

Comment: hey, I just edited my answer, is that acceptable? what do you mean by " but it did not seem totally relevant to the OP" for the linked post?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that with

```
f.getClass
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does work in REPL but I want to do this from within a program. Instead I get `class main.examples.Test$$anonfun$1`